# How to remove message about loaded modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, debugging

Some months ago I've written a Flask application. I got back to work, but now after start I got a few screens of `loaded modules`:

```
formnoreload$ python main.py 
...
matplotlib - DEBUG - __init__.<module>() [l. 1449]:
    interactive is False
matplotlib - DEBUG - __init__.<module>() [l. 1450]:
    platform is linux
matplotlib - DEBUG - __init__.<module>() [l. 1451]:
    loaded modules: ['sys', 'builtins', '_frozen_importlib',
[lengthy list continues...]
```

Is it possible to remove this information about `loaded modules`? How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Almost done:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import set_loglevel
set_loglevel("warning")
```

Most of logging information, about loaded modules, has been turned off.

Comment: I've just found that it is not an issue with `flask`, but with `matplotlib`. Does anyone know how to turn off printing of all these information?

Comment: Got the `matplotlib` solution:

`from matplotlib.pyplot import set_loglevel
set_loglevel("warning")`

-> no more info about `loaded modules` -- just PIL logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to this problem would be:

```
import logging
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

`matplotlib` and `PIL` messages were disabled.
This was added *before* importing anything from `matplotlib'.

**EDIT**

Even better solution would be this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

That way the tonne of information from `matplotlib` and `PIL` is disabled, but necessary, own debug logs, go through (`level=logging.WARNING` works too).

(ChatGPT assisted)